# Spring Boot : Can we use reactive Webfilter in existing spring mvc application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I am trying to incorporate spring reactive Webflux webfilter to existing spring boot web application and getting below error.

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

The bean 'conversionServicePostProcessor', defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class],
could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in class path resource
[org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/reactive/WebFluxSecurityConfiguration.class] and overriding is disabled.

question:  Can we use reactive Webfilter in existing spring mvc application?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't directly use reactive filters; the MVC stack uses the Servlet API, which has its own (blocking) filter mechanism. You might be able to extract the business logic into a common class and reference it from both a reactive and a blocking implementation.

Comment: Thanks Chrylis. so i can't use also OncePerRequestFilter and WebFilter together?